# No module named tenserflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0

i came to this problem when im about to generate tfrecord for my test and training data. can anyone help me?

```
C:\Object_detection\models-master\research\object_detection>python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/test_labels.csv --image_dir=images/test --output_path=test.record
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 17, in 
from tensorflow.python.framework.versions import VERSION
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I am really stuck lol. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
pip show tensorflow
```

to check you tensorflow version.
It's possible that you will need to downgrade or upgrade you tf package to be able to run your tfrecord. Check the documentation of the function to know the version you need.